# Swapping elements in vertex C++

Tags: c++

Hey guys I am trying to swap and rotate my vertex 90 degrees but when I am printing it it is only showing

- ct
- ao

when it should show

- ct
- ao
- tm

I know that my problem is that not enough space is in the vertex when I am swapping them since when I pushed tom and cat making a vertex[3][2] but now I am trying to make it [2][3] so I know that is the problem and I tried to reserve space but that wont work either since it will just overwrite anything in there. So any help would be amazing thanks guys

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

    int main() {
        std::vector<std::string> lines;
        //lines.reserve(100);

        lines.push_back("tom");
        lines.push_back("cat");

        for(int r = 0; r < lines.size(); r++)//swapping
        {
            for(int c = r; c < lines[r].size(); c++)
            {
                std::swap(lines[r][c], lines[c][r]);
            }
        }

        for(int r = 0; r < lines.size(); r++)//where I am rotating
        {
            for(int c =0; c < lines[c].size()/2; c++)
            {
                std::swap(lines[r][c], lines[r][lines[c].size()-c-1]);
            }
        }

        for(int i=0; i<lines.size(); i++)
            std::cout << lines[i] << "\n";


        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: You add two three-letter strings to the vector, and that's it. You never add a third string to the vector, so you can't get three lines of output. But you *do* have *undefined behavior* since you access the vector out of bounds (the only valid indexes in the vector is `0` and `1`, but you also use index `2` which is out of bounds).

Comment: yea i realize that i'm going out of bounds but I am just wondering how can i increase my size of the vector accordingly without overwriting elements.

Comment: After the swap you could push_back() to a new vector and delete the old one.

Comment: In the first set of loops, when you notice that the index `c` will be out of bounds of the vector, then push back a string of size `r`. Note that you can't use `r < lines.size()` as the outer loop condition there anymore, use temporary variable with the original size. I don't know if this will solve your problem or not (which is why I didn't write this as an answer) but I *think* it *might* work.

Comment: Joachim-The problem with that is that would insert a string that i dont want swapped or even if it was a blank space i do not want it in the vector. Is there no way to just edit the vector size? incrementing it by one if this was integers it would be easier but sadly it is strings.

Comment: That's why I say that the condition of the outer loop needs to be changed, you can't call `lines.size()` there but use another variable which have been initialized to `lines.size()` *before* you add an element to the vector.

Comment: ok thanks it is semi working I just have a question how do i insert a string with a given size like if it said 5 it would pushback 5 spaces or 4 it would pushback 4 spaces the thing is it can be any number

Comment: Nvm thanks for your guy's help but that turned out to be a really convoluted way of doing it. It also results in alot more problems when trying to remove the inserted column. Hopefully someone else is able to help later thanks anyway guys.

Answer (score 0):

Use two vectors.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    vector<string> v1;
    vector<string> v2;

    v1.push_back("tom");
    v1.push_back("cat");
    for (auto& it : v1) {
        cout << it << endl;
    }

    swap(v1.front(), v1.back());
    for (auto& it : v1) {
        cout << it << endl;
    }

    auto first = v1.front();
    auto last  = v1.back();

    for (string::iterator it1 = first.begin(), it2 = last.begin(); it1 != first.end(); ++it1, ++it2) {
        stringstream ss;
        string s;
        ss << *it1 << *it2;
        ss >> s;
        v2.push_back(s);
    }

    for (auto& it : v2) {
        cout << it << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output

```
tom
cat

cat
tom

ct
ao
tm
```